# Something happened to Swap; it is not used by default

Tags: swap, fstab

I always have to go to `gparted` and then turn my swap on. The swap space isn't used by default and if I turn the swap on, the swap is not used! How can I make the swap space be used by default at boot? [image: screenshot of System Monitor showing swap as "not available"]

Comment: Stop posting the same question to multiple sites, please. You've already posted it here: http://superuser.com/questions/673967/something-happened-to-swap. I deleted it on Super User now. In the future, choose one site you want to post on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information should be set in `/etc/fstab`

You want a line something like - `/dev/sdb3  none  swap  sw  0 0` with the first item set to match your device details. Any swap lines with noauto will be ignored.

I believe this configuration is fairly consistent between *nix systems, see `man fstab` for more info.